# How to write DVD from bootable pen drive

Tags: usb, dvd, iso-image

I have a bootable USB pen drive which has bootable Ubuntu. Now I want to write to a DVD from the pen drive. How can I do this? Please explain it, so that I can save the software for future.

Comment: You don't need to wait for an answer.  This has already been asked before.  If you enter "create iso from current system" in the search box, there are many similar questions already answered.  Check out: http://superuser.com/questions/456899/create-ubuntu-installation-of-current-system .

Comment: It sounds like JaskaranZap just wants to burn some DVD's, not create a custom install iso with Remastersys

Comment: Can you clarify what your objective is (simply write content to the DVD drive vs. save a backup of the pen drive ("save the software"), vs. create a bootable copy of the pen drive on DVD?

Comment: Thank you, @Journeyman - I didn't know how to mark it this way.  But the questions and my answer are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to burn a new (data, iso, etc) dvd, you'll have to use a program like k3b, Brasero, xfburn... search & install with your package manager (Software Center / apt / Synaptic / aptitude).

If you wanted to burn a new bootable Ubuntu dvd specifically this Ubuntu community help page has tips:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
Or this link has more pictures, for basic Ubuntu (Unity I think): http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to read a bootable USB to an ISO: Just use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) - it does precisely what you are asking for.

The program is self-explanatory.

Here is a search that has links to reviews and instructions:  [Rufus search results on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rufus%20copy%20iso%20to%20usb)

Then you can use your favorite ISO burner to get it on a DVD.  I use [CDburnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) on all my machines, from Vista to Win8.1

It has only one limitation:   It only works with optical disks.  That's why you need Rufus to read the stick first.

Comment: It definitely is a duplicate  but I don't know how to make it show up that way.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/477569/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-dvd-iso-from-a-usb-drive